# SQL Server - poor performance during Insert transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, insert, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure which executes a query and return the line into variables like below:

```
SELECT @item_id = I.ID, @label_ID = SL.label_id,
FROM tb_A I 
LEFT JOIN tb_B SL ON I.ID = SL.item_id
WHERE I.NUMBER = @VAR
```

I have a IF to check if @label_ID is null or not. If it is null, it goes to INSERT statement, otherwise it goes to UPDATE statement. Let's focus on INSERT where I know I'm having problems. The INSERT part is like below:

```
IF @label_ID IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_B (item_id, label_qrcode, label_barcode, data_leitura, data_inclusao)
    VALUES (@item_id, @label_qrcode, @label_barcode, @data_leitura, GETDATE())
END
```

So, tb_B has a PK in ID column and a FK in item_ID column which refers to column ID in tb_A table.

I ran SQL Server Profiler and I saw that sometimes the duration for this stored procedure takes around 2300ms and the normal average for this is 16ms.

I ran the "Execution Plan" and the biggest cost is in the "Clustered Index Insert" component. Showing below:

[Estimated Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NvMQ.png)

[Actual Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bh0H.png)

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvtUu.png)

More details about the tables:

```
tb_A Storage:
Index space: 6.853,188 MB
Row count: 45988842
Data space: 5.444,297 MB

tb_B Storage:
Index space: 1.681,688 MB
Row count: 15552847
Data space: 1.663,281 MB

Statistics for INDEX 'PK_tb_B'.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name                            Updated                         Rows                            Rows Sampled                    Steps                           Density                         Average Key Length              String Index                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK_tb_B                     Sep 23 2018  2:30AM             15369616                        15369616                        5                               1                               4                               NO                                                              15369616                        

All Density                     Average Length                  Columns                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6.506343E-08                    4                               id               

Histogram Steps                 
RANGE_HI_KEY                    RANGE_ROWS                      EQ_ROWS                         DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS             AVG_RANGE_ROWS                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                               0                               1                               0                               1                               
8192841                         8192198                         1                               8192198                         1                               
8270245                         65535                           1                               65535                           1                               
15383143                        7111878                         1                               7111878                         1                               
15383144                        0                               1                               0                               1                               


Statistics for INDEX 'IDX_tb_B_ITEM_ID'.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name                            Updated                         Rows                            Rows Sampled                    Steps                           Density                         Average Key Length              String Index                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDX_tb_B_ITEM_ID            Sep 23 2018  2:30AM             15369616                        15369616                        12                              1                               7.999424                        NO                                                              15369616                        

All Density                     Average Length                  Columns                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6.50728E-08                     3.999424                        item_id                         
6.506343E-08                    7.999424                        item_id, id      

Histogram Steps                 
RANGE_HI_KEY                    RANGE_ROWS                      EQ_ROWS                         DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS             AVG_RANGE_ROWS                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                0                               2214                            0                               1                               
16549857                        0                               1                               0                               1                               
29907650                        65734                           1                               65734                           1                               
32097131                        131071                          1                               131071                          1                               
32296132                        196607                          1                               196607                          1                               
32406913                        98303                           1                               98303                           1                               
40163331                        7700479                         1                               7700479                         1                               
40237216                        65535                           1                               65535                           1                               
47234636                        6946815                         1                               6946815                         1                               
47387143                        131071                          1                               131071                          1                               
47439431                        31776                           1                               31776                           1                               
47439440                        0                               1                               0                               1
```

[PK_tb_B Index fragmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV7tU.png)

[IDX_tb_B_Item_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdmqW.png)

Is there any best practices where I can apply and make this execution duration stable?

Hope you can help me !!!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I doubt the insert itself is the problem. The more likely is short term blocking or server resources in general. I'd expect consistent duration otherwise.

Comment: This is the only process which access the table tb_B... but the table tb_A is used in other processes.
Where can I see if server resources is OK or NOT?

Comment: Blocking could also occur due to locks being held on tbl_A or tbl_A rows during the referencial constraint check. I can't be specific about OK or NOT but the general approach is monitor during good times and bad. For example, a large query during the insert could use excessive CPU, memory, and disk, resulting in slower inserts during that time.

Comment: `takes around 2300ms` which statement does take that much? You know, profiler allows tracing separate statements. About execution plan: `insert` is THE ONLY operation performed with this statement. And you are worried about "90%"? a) it is the only command you're executing b) it is 90% of almost zero execution time. Statistics make no sense here. You'd better show us filegrowth settings. And 2s is more likely a locking issue.

Comment: You have high page fullness. If your application does a lot of inserts try setting a smaller fill factor. Read this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/

Comment: What DbType is the column item_id from tb_B?

Comment: I tried the approuch of changing my clustered index from tb_B to NONClustered. I cound't feel any change in the results.
Now I will try the fill factor settings...
I also believe that some query in tb_A is locking resources and it is impacting tb_B inserting. I'm going to check that too.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably that the problem is the DbType of the clustered index. Clustered indexes store the data in the table based on the key values. By default, your primary key is created with a clustered index. This is often the best place to have it,
but not always. If you have, for example, a clustered index over a NVARCHAR column, every time that an INSERT is performed, needs to find the right place to insert the new record. For example, if your table have one million rows, with registers ordered alphabetically, and your new register starts with A, then your clustered index needs to move registers from B to Z to put your new register in the A group. If your new register stars with Z, then moves a smaller number of records, but this doesn't mean that its fine too. If you don´t have a column that let you insert new register sequentially, then you can create an identity column for this or have another column that logically is sequential to any transaction entered regardless of the system, for example, a datetime column that registers the time at the insert ocurrs.

If you want more info, please check this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: the Dbtype is INT and they are the same dbType in both tables.